# Make HTML Table behave like `justify-content: space-between`

Tags: html, css, frontend

is there a way to make table columns behave like the justify-content: space-between from flexbox.
I want the first and the last column be at the end and the start and the rest should be fitted in the middle of these two.

[image]

Comment: add `width:100%` on table

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior using a combination of CSS and HTML

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="first">First Column</td>
    <td class="middle">Middle Column 1</td>
    <td class="middle">Middle Column 2</td>
    <td class="last">Last Column</td>
  </tr>
</table>


.table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.first {
  text-align: left;
}

.last {
  text-align: right;
}

.middle {
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: how would this work when i want to have `th{text-align: center;}`

Comment: td {text-align: center;}